# AttributeError: 'LinearSVC' object has no attribute 'coef_'

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, svm, multilabel-classification

I use LinearSVC for a multi-label classification problem. Since `LinearSVC` does not provide a `predict_proba` method, I decided to use `CalibratedClassifierCV` to scale the decision function into [0, 1] probabilities.

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV

classifier = CalibratedClassifierCV(LinearSVC(class_weight = 'balanced', max_iter = 100000)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

However, I also need to access the weights `coef_`, but `classifier.base_estimator.coef_` raise the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'LinearSVC' object has no attribute 'coef_'
```

I thought `classifier.base_estimator` returned the calibrated classifier and allowed to access all its attributes. Thanks in advance for explaining me what I missunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into this problem and it turns out that you need to look at the underlying calibrated models (this is not stored at `classifier.base_estimator` as seems inutitive):

```py
classifier = CalibratedClassifierCV(LinearSVC(
    class_weight = 'balanced', 
    max_iter = 100000
)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# access the weights of each trained classifier here
trained_classifiers = classifier.calibrated_classifiers_

# look at the first one for example
first_trained_classifier = trained_classifiers[0]

print(first_trained_classifier.base_estimator.coef_)
```

This will output something like:

```
array([[-2.92536427e-01, -4.09833721e-02, -1.05421453e-01, ...,
        -1.10948730e-01, -9.39921540e-03, -4.10724956e-03],
       [-4.02743557e-01, -3.56716135e-01,  2.30114807e-01, ...,
        -4.56128723e-02,  0.00000000e+00,  1.08420217e-17],
       [ 1.90550610e-01,  3.70755554e-02, -9.41194493e-02, ...,
        -1.38777878e-17,  3.87705771e-02,  9.26296583e-02],
       ...,
       [-5.93576666e-02,  1.03790828e-01, -7.95228024e-02, ...,
        -1.50562796e-01,  4.56042004e-02,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 2.72370524e-01,  8.71504993e-02,  1.30601404e-03, ...,
        -1.55804453e-01, -3.92344382e-02,  6.05113193e-02],
       [-3.91555037e-01, -1.31277960e-01, -4.62863392e-02, ...,
        -1.67542946e-01,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00]])
```